# Pip3 requirements not installing the right version of a library

Tags: python, pip

I am using pip3 to install python3 packages on a cleared python virtual environment (therefore the package list is basically empty at first), using a requirements.txt file:

```
bcrypt==3.1.6
cffi==1.12.2
coverage==4.5.3
flask==1.0.2
flask_cors==3.0.7
flask-sqlalchemy==2.3.2
gensim==3.7.1
google_compute_engine==2.8.13
matplotlib==3.0.3
nltk==3.4
numpy==1.16.2
pyjwt==1.7.1
pymysql==0.9.3
pyyaml==3.13
sklearn==0.0
sqlalchemy==1.3.1
tensorflow==1.5

pip3 install --no-cache-dir -I -r requirements.txt
```

The option *no-cache-dir* is used because I already executed the requirements file so I have libraries in cache and I don't want them to mess with the installation since I want the file to work as intended even the first time you use it.

All of the libraries versions written in this file (bcrypt v. 3.1.6, cffi v. 1.12.2, etc.) are currently the latest available version, except for the tensorflow library. The problem is that each time I try to install the requirements, *pip3 freeze* tells me that the tensorflow version is 1.13.1 which is the latest. Then I'm forced to uninstall tensorflow, and reinstall it using pip3 to get the right version:

```
pip3 uninstall tensorflow
pip3 install tensorflow==1.5
```

Why does this command line works, and not the one in the requirements file? Since I'm doing exactly what I saw I should do, I'm a little bit dumbfounded...

Comment: pip isn't too good at dependency resolution. We probably need to see the whole requirements.txt at the very least in order to understand what may have gone wrong.

Comment: I updated the subject. The versions on the other libraries are here to have a future proof file.

Comment: @Arne I forgot to tag you, in case you didn't noticed my reply.

Comment: Sorry, I had to go for a while. I had gotten a ping for the initial message, no worries. I can't reproduce your error btw: http://dpaste.com/2NBPVWE

Comment: If you're comfortable with docker, you can use that container to search for differences between your environment and that one.

Answer (score 0):

No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.5

If you want to see, try this command

```
pip3 install tensorflow==1.5
```

Alternative installation:

```
pip3 install https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/archive/v1.5.0-rc1.zip
```

or you can compile from source code

Comment: Edit: Sorry for the bad indentation and things, I don't know how to do it in a comment...

As I said above, *pip3 install tensorflow==1.5* is actually the way for me to install tensorflow v. 1.5 so I don't understand the error you get.

`Collecting tensorflow==1.5
  Downloading
 ...
Successfully installed absl-py-0.7.1 bleach-1.5.0 html5lib-0.9999999 markdown-3.1 numpy-1.16.2 protobuf-3.7.1 setuptools-40.8.0 six-1.12.0 tensorflow-1.5.0 tensorflow-tensorboard-1.5.1 werkzeug-0.15.1 wheel-0.33.1`

Then, with *pip3 freeze* I get `tensorflow==1.5.0` (plus all the other dependencies).